# PostMapping Logic errors

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a method in my service that can save a fruit in all the stores that I have. It works well in main method, but not with Postman. When I test with Postman it creates just one instance of the fruit.

*Service code*

```
@Override
public Fruit addFruit(Fruit f) {
   Iterable<Store> stores=storeService.getAllStores();
   for (Store store : stores) {
     Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
     fruit.setStore(store);
     fruit.setAlert(f.getAlert());
     fruit.setCategory(f.getCategory());
     fruit.setDesignation(f.getDesignation());
     fruit.setLign(f.getLign());
     fruit.setReference(f.getReference());
     fruit.setStock(f.getStock());
     f.setStore(store);
     fruitRepository.save(fruit);
     }
 
  return f;    
}
```

*postman Json *

```
{
"reference":"reference1",
"category":"Citrus",
"designation":"Orange and Lemon",
"lign":20,
"stock":60
}
```

Comment: Please do add your controller code and `storeService.getAllStores()` code.

Comment: How may stores does `storeService.getAllStores()` return ?

Comment: @O.Badr it return Array with 3 stores

Answer (score 0):

*getAllstore services*

```
 @Override
 public Iterable<Store> getAllStores() {
 return storeRepository.findAll();
 }
```

*Controller*

```
@Path("/fruits")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Fruit addProduit(@RequestBody Fruit f) {
    return fruitService.addFruit(f);
}
```

Comment: You need to post this code in your original question, and delete this "answer"

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a collection of `Fruit` instead of one `Fruit` in the Controller and also in the Service, so you can return back what you have created in the database, and you can also check the result in Postman.

Service:

```
@Override 
public Set<Fruit> addFruit(Fruit f) {
  Iterable<Store> stores=storeService.getAllStores();
  Set<Fruit> createdFruits = new HashSet<>(  stores.size() )
  for (Store store : stores) { 
    Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
    fruit.setStore(store);
    fruit.setAlert(f.getAlert());
    fruit.setCategory(f.getCategory());
    fruit.setDesignation(f.getDesignation());
    fruit.setLign(f.getLign());
    fruit.setReference(f.getReference());
    fruit.setStock(f.getStock());
 //f.setStore(store);  // You don't need this 
    createdFruits.add( fruitRepository.save(fruit) ); 
  } 

  return createdFruits; 
}
```

Controller:

```
@Path("/fruits") 
@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public Set<Fruit> addProduit(@RequestBody Fruit f) {
   return fruitService.addFruit(f);
}
```